# HttpMessageHandler с BeforeRequest и AfterResponse

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httpclient

Задача:
Добавить JWT токен перед отправкой HTTP запросов используя HttpMessageHandler. Имеется либа, которая принимает только HttpMessageHandler.
Нужно реализовать это используя все бенефиты IHttpMessageHandlerFactory или другой фабрики.

Была такая идея, но не получится ткк HttpMessageHandler.SendAsync internal

```
public class InterceptableHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private readonly HttpMessageHandler baseHandler;

    public InterceptableHttpMessageHandler(HttpMessageHandler baseHandler) // baseHandler from  IHttpMessageHandlerFactory 
    {
        
        this.baseHandler = baseHandler;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // call "on before"
        this.baseHandler.SendAsync(...) // internal :(
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Создал запускаемый фидл: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lQwx2Y
Фидл не решает проблему, ткк все равно HttpMessageHandler создается вручную, но примерно показывает проблему.
И да, baseUrl должно меняется в рантайме, поэтому не уверен на счет неймд клиентов и всего такого.

Comment: Чтобы "дёрнуть" закрытый метод, есть рефлексия.

Comment: а где тут добавление JWT перед отправкой?

Comment: Сделать класс-наследник и перегрузить метод `SendAsync` с добавлением необходимого кода.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov но я хочу получать инстансы используя HttpMessageHandlerFactory и имея все преимущества такого подхода: пул конокшенов, лайфтайм менеджмент и тд. В примере я имел ввиду,  что получу HttpMessageHandler из фабрики и он будет в пуле и т.д. Если я просто создам наследника, то вопрос как его инстанциировать.

Comment: @Grundy в "// call "on before", сама реализация добавления токена не важна, главное иметь доступ к хедерам

Comment: @aepot да, но хотелось бы без рефлексии. Задача, как по мне, бытовая  должно быть лучшее решение

Comment: У фабрики есть несколько конструкторов. Используйте тот, который принимает параметры, позволяющие создавать экземпляры нужного типа.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можете, пожалуйста, уточнить. Вы имеете ввиду named http clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DelegatingHandler](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.delegatinghandler?view=netcore-3.1)

```cs
public class InterceptableHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public InterceptableHttpMessageHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
    {

    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.OnBefore(request);

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void OnBefore(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("testheader", "testheaderval");
    }
}
```

Comment: Да! Точно, мои навыки гугления меня подвели, но пример был близко.